PowerBI - How to select a specified date range
PowerBI - How to select a specified date range to keep only those rows in PowerBI
I want to select a date range from 01/03/24 to 01/04/24 (as an example date range).
I have tried the following.
FILTER(
    'formfull',
    'formfull'[upLoad_output] >= DATE(2024, 1, 1) && 'formfull'[upLoad_output] <= DATE(2024, 12, 31)
)


This errors to the following.
"Total Literal expected"



You're trying to use DAX when you need to use M in Power Query. If your column is a date, select the filter in the column header and then between.

It generates code as follows:
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Date] >= #datetime(2024, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0) and [Date] <= #datetime(2024, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0))


Will this run for large datasets (>>500 million rows), as PowerBI is crashing when attempting to select a year, month, week and three day periods.

Should be fine. Are you connecting to a database? If so, query folding should occur. You can right click on a step name and view native query to ensure the correct SQL is being sent back.

I am connecting to a database and filtered down through the dataset to fully open the cols and rows. Right clicked on the step name, but the 'view native query' is greyed out.

Sometimes it is greyed out on an individual step. Is View Native Query available in any of the steps? Which database are you connecting to?

I am in the Transform window and 'view native query' in all steps are greyed out. I am using an inhouse database hosted on Azure. The dataset is a json file.

What type of database is it? Might be best to ask a new question so you can post all the info and screenshots. Others might be able to help too.

TBH, I do not know the details of database as its a third party database holding sensitive data.  We access a json file using an API link, filter down in PowerBI for smaller datasets.  For this larger dataset we use R (an imperfect solution) but want to do this in PowerBI (if possible). Selecting rows on conditions.  Perhaps it takes a much longer time than I have been leaving it (4 to 5 hours).

The idea is to access the json file in PowerBI and save multiple datasets of a day, week or month date range each and then concatenate those datasets in Python/R for reloading to PowerBI for high level reporting.

I understand but the devil is in the detail and you have a data pipleline which isn't clear at the moment. We need to know all the steps from source to Power BI, connection types, data types, data sizes etc. Best put this all in a new question with details.

Thank you davidebacci.  Will see if I can access more information on the database and aim to post a new question.
